# Service function in Angularjs strange style

Tags: angularjs

I have asked a similar question but got no correct answer. The question is about the service function in angularjs. When I use service function to define an angularjs service in a abnormal way, it actually works fine. I cannot find any documentation for this style. See the code below:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('myService',function(){
    return {
        show:function() {
            console.log('show');
        }
    }
});

var myController=function($scope,myService) {
    myService.show();
}

angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', myController);

myController.$inject=['$scope','myService'];
```

But usually service function should use this.show=function(){} kind of this style? Am I correct? So what happened.

Answer (score 1):

It is called in angular terms `factory` and not `service`. Don't ever create services like that: you are confusing other developers. This is a correct way: change `service` to `factory`, it will create exactly the same service but it is not confusing anymore:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myService',function(){
   return {
    show:function(){
        console.log('show');
   }}
});
```

See [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to learn more.

What happens? Seems angular recognizes you are using the factory, but as long as this is not documented it is probably not going to be the same in the future versions, so although *your method* is working it is still not supported.

Comment: and it is confusing you... That is what I was talking about.